# magento over-ride title.phtml

Tags: magento2, overrides

I want to over-ride title phtml file so i copied it from

```
F:/xampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml
```

Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title.phtml

To

```
F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\design\frontend\GWtheme\GW\templates\html\title.phtml
```

Here Gwtheme\Gw is custom theme foldernames

But when i flush cache and check the files seems not be over-ridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first keep your theme name in small case as per magento recommendation.
Keep theme name `gw`.

After create custom theme, you have to set your theme inside admin.

> Stores -> Configation -> General -> Design

Set your custom theme and save.

Now you can override core template, you have missing core module name here is **Magento_Theme**

Path is, `app/code/design/frontend/GWtheme/gw/Magento_Theme/templates/html/title.phtml`

Now You can deploy your content using,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Remove var folder from root and check again.

Comment: One more question for over-riding css, I want to change nav color, i did this and flushed cached but not working,
F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\web\css\source\lib\_navigation.less

F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\design\frontend\GWtheme\gw\web\css\source\lib\_navigation.less

and on top of the navigation i placed @_nav-background-color:#fff; to change nav color but see to be not working

Comment: frist delete pub/static/frontend folder and you can deploy command, php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: i did that, but the i did for css is correct ? to copy nav.less and add different color in overridden file?

Comment: How Can I overwrite a page title html, including extra tags for a specific page?